# Use of $? in an if statement conditional expression

Tags: linux, bash

Take the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls /sdfg

if [ $? -gt 0 ]
then
        echo "Command failed: $?"
else
        echo "Command succeeded: $?"
fi
```

The output will be:

```
ls: cannot access /sdfg: No such file or directory
Command failed: 0
```

The failed ls command actually returns 2, the if statement catches this, and echos command failed, but why does $? get updated to zero? It looks like the if/then lines are being treated as a new command.

Comment: `[` is a command (called "test")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is actually a binary, not just some punctuation:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51920 Feb 18 07:37 /usr/bin/[
$ /usr/bin/[ --version
[ (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

and on some systems may be a symlink to `test`.

So here

```
if [ $? -gt 0 ]
```

`$?` is the result of your `ls` call, but here

```
    echo "Command failed: $?"
```

`$?` is the result of having executed `[` on the previous line.

If you want to test `$?` from a command multiple times, you'll have to stuff it into a temp var:

```
ls blahblah
temp=$?
if [ $temp ... ]
if [ $temp ... ]
```

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: The temp variable is not necessary if you avoid running `[` which is often an antipattern anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should rarely need to examine `$?` explicitly anyway, since doing that is the purpose of `if` (and other conditional builtins like `while`). The proper way to write that is

```
if ls /sdfg; then
    echo "Command succeeded: $?"
else
    echo "Command failed: $?"
fi
```

Notice how the failure case is now the `else` branch. (If you don't particularly care about preserving the failure exit code, you can use `if ! ls`... and keep the success branch in the `else`, but your question seems to be specifically about preserving it, which negation with `!` will not do.)

Answer (score 1):

Collect the return value **immediately** after the command being tested if you're going to reuse it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# best-practice: collect *on the same line*, so any logging added in the future doesn't
# ...change your exit status.
ls /sdfg; retval=$?

if [ $retval -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "Command failed: $retval" # 
else
        echo "Command succeeded: $retval"
fi
```

---

However, the best practice is to directly operate on the command's exit status without needing to refer to `$?` at all:

```
if ls /sdfg; then
  echo "Command succeeded: $?"
else
  echo "Command failed: $?"
fi
```