# Bash idle session times greater than 15 min

Tags: bash

I need help completing this. Trying to take user sessions sitting idle for greater than 15 minutes which aren't being kicked off by `sshd_config` and kill them. this is what I have to pull the sessions, how do I filter for greater than 15 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

for output in $(w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5 | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $2}')

do

echo "$output \> 15:00"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Awk anyway, a shell loop is a clumsy antipattern. Awk already knows how to loop over lines; use it.

A serious complication is that the output from `w` is system-dependent and typically reformatted for human legibility.

```
tripleee$ w | head -n 4
 8:16  up 37 days, 19:02, 17 users, load averages: 3.49 3.21 3.11
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
tripleee console  -                27Aug18 38days -
tripleee s003     -                27Aug18    38 ssh -t there screen -D -r
```

If yours looks similar, probably filter out anything where the IDLE field contains non-numeric information

```
w -h | awk '$5 ~ /[^0-9]/ || $5 > 15'
```

This prints the entire `w` output line. You might want to extract just the TTY field (`{print $2}` on my system) and figure out from there which session to kill.

A more fruitful approach on Linux-like systems is probably to examine the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: thanks, i looked into awk in more depth and was able to use it to filter down to only the events i needed.

w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5 | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $0}'|cut -d':' -f1 | awk '$2>15{print$0}'|sed -n '/.00s/!p'|awk '{print $1}'

Then i'm taking the output here and using UID to find sshd PID from ps aux, pipe that to kill -9, and idle sessions are dead.

Comment: All of that should be easily refactored to a single Awk script; perhaps see also [useless use of `sed`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this …

```
for i in $(w --no-header | awk '{print $4}')
do
echo $i | grep days > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   echo "greater that 15 mins"
fi
echo $i | grep min> /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
   mins=$(echo $i | sed -e's/mins//g')
   if [ $min -gt 15 ]
   then
       echo "Greater than 15 mins"
   fi
fi
done
```

The tricky part is going to be figuring out what `pid` to kill.

Comment: This contains multiple quoting errors; you might want to check the output from http://shellcheck.net/ on this script. Also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793446/use-of-in-an-if-statement-conditional-expression

Comment: I didn't actually test the above script. I am just trying to help Austin by giving him some ideas. I assume Austin will actually write his script and test it.

Comment: figuring out the PID to kill was the easy part, trying to extract the user to pipe output to my other command was where i was having issues. To find the PID and kill it was a simple 1 line

sudo kill -9 '$(ps aux |grep sshd | grep -w "^$i" | grep -v grep | awk "{print $2}")'

where $i is the user who's session you intend to kill